# Existe alguma forma de misturar o SO em inglês e Português?

Tags: suporte, comunidade

Eu gosto de responder perguntas no SO em inglês. Tem alguma forma de eu acessar a lista de perguntas novas do SO Inglês e do em Português em uma única página? Além disso, tem alguma forma de fazer o SO em Português ter as mesmas tags favoritas/ignoradas que em inglês ou eu vou ter que manter isso atualizado na mão?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aparentemente o stackexchange tem uma funcionalidade de filtros que permite criar uma homepage customizada com perguntas de mais de um site:

http://stackexchange.com/filters/new

Consegui fazer uma que mistura os dois SOs. Ainda não sei direito se é visível para qualquer um ou só pra mim e se atualiza tão rápido quanto visitar as páginas separadamente:

http://stackexchange.com/filters/118110/stackoverflows

Comment: Tem isso mesmo, não achei que resolveria o seu problema. è um bom índice.

Answer (score 6):

Não há como, são duas comunidades absolutamente distintas utilizando uma estrutura diferente. O único jeito é manter duas páginas abertas mesmo.

O que ainda será feito é a troca do nosso ícone para ficar mais fácil identificar qual página é SO e qual é SOpt.

Você terá que fazer a configuração das tags aqui manualmente. Não tem e não está prevista nenhuma ferramenta para importar essas configurações, até porque ele não funcionaria muito bem.

Temos inclusive algumas regras um pouco diferentes aqui. Somos mais amplos e menos seletivos com as perguntas que podem ser feitas aqui. Mas não muito :)